# Determine Cipher Suite used in Server

Tags: security, networking, infrastructure

I am trying to find out what Cipher Suite being used in our Server.I am wondering any tools to give us the information ? I know Wireshark will provides such details if i am not wrong.

Any suggestion greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The cipher suite used by the server for any given session is chosen from a list presented by the client. There isn't one single answer. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Test your server with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ A list of cipher suites offered by your server is among the reported items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the negotiated one, you can find this information (for instance) in Chrome -> DevTools -> Security. This is the output for `https://www.google.com`:

[image]

Please note that the handshake follows the approach of "*we (the client) provide what we support, they (the server) choose something from that list*". You can check with Wireshark how this is exchanged following a great read on [the first few milliseconds of a HTTPS connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html).